# Terraform JSON configuration

Tags: json, bash, terraform, environment

I am trying to take a JSON input, complete some validation/transforms on it, and apply it as a terraform template. What would be most convenient is to pass the terraform template json (in env variables) definitions of resources, and have terraform apply those, however I cannot get this to work (I have a variables.tf file which uses the TF_VAR variables to set configuration, and am passing in JSON config per the terraform documetnation)

Is there a standard way of doing this? (Passing tf json definitions via env vars to terraform to apply?)

Comment: What is your TF code? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about what the error is, since there is no code and no error log or example to be reproduced.
I will assume you already know how to pass and access environment variables (if not check this [medium post](https://medium.com/codex/how-to-use-environment-variables-on-terraform-f2ab6f95f82d)), and you are receiving a large "string" inside terraform and want to read it as json.

The solution for it would be to use the functions jsondecode/jsonencode.

Just little reminder, when posting a question, if you paste the code with it, it makes it easier for people to understand what you are trying to do. The quality of answers will be higher.